# Swift: Programmatically create a new calendar with a fixed name if that name does not exist (instead of doing it manually in the iPhone)

Tags: swift, calendar

You can create a new calendar in your iPhone, give it a specific name and set it as the default calendar (mark it with a check mark). I want to do this from Swift code if a calendar with that name does not exist. If a calendar with that specific name exists then I do not want to create another one. Then I want to set the calendar with that name as the default calendar. I have some code but I could not find the missing part at the end (how to append this calendar to the other calendars and set it as the default calendar).

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
let calendars = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent) as [EKCalendar]
var exists = false
for calendar in calendars {
       if calendar.title == "newcal" {
                    exists = true                        
       }         
}
if exists==false {
       let newCalendar=EKCalendar()
       newCalendar.title="newcal"                
       ...

}
```

Comment: This question is too broad, and it's unclear specifically what you're asking.  Amy, just so you know, if you ask too many poorly received questions, your account will be suspended from asking questions, so I recommend slowing down on the question train.

Comment: I added more details.

Answer (score 4):

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
let calendars = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent) as [EKCalendar]
var exists = false
for calendar in calendars {
   if calendar.title == "newcal" {
       exists = true
   }
}

var err : NSError?
if exists==false {
   let newCalendar = EKCalendar(forEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent, eventStore:eventStore)
   newCalendar.title="newcal"
   newCalendar.source = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents.source
   let ok = eventStore.saveCalendar(newCalendar, commit:true, error:&err)
   println(ok)
}
```